# How can I tab away from a Fl_Button in FLTK?

Tags: c++, fltk

I have a custom class, `CustomButton` that extends `Fl_Button`. On my screen there are a bunch of `Fl_Input` and `CustomButton` widgets that I want to be able to navigate between using a tab keypress. Tabbing between input fields works fine, but once a `CustomButton` gets focus, I can't seem to tab away from it.

Here's my handle function

```
int CustomButton::handle ( int event )
{
  int is_event_handled = 0;
  switch (event)
  {
    case FL_KEYBOARD:
      // If the keypress was enter, toggle the button on/off
      if (Fl::event_key() == FL_Enter || Fl::event_key() == FL_KP_Enter)
      {
        // Do stuff...
      }
      is_event_handled = 1;
      break;

    case FL_FOCUS:
    case FL_UNFOCUS:
      // The default Fl_Button handling does not allow Focus/Unfocus
      // for the button so mark the even as handled to skip the Fl_Button processing
      is_event_handled = 1;
      break;

    default:
      is_event_handled = 0;
      break;
  }

  if ( is_event_handled == 1 ) return 1;
  return Fl_Round_Button::handle ( event );
}
```

I am using fltk 1.1.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was my `CustomButton::handle()` returning `1` after a `FL_KEYBOARD` event without actually using the tab key press.

Moving `is_event_handled = 1` into the if statement lets me consume the `FL_Enter` keypress only and lets other widgets (i.e. the Fl_Group that controls navigation) take any other keypresses.

Alternatively get rid of the `if` and replace with something like

```
switch(Fl::event_key())
{
    case FL_Enter:
    case FL_KP_Enter:
        // Do stuff
        is_event_handled = 1;
        break;
    default:
        is_event_handled = 0;
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a very simple, minimal example which demonstrates how to control the focus, please check the [navigation.cxx](https://gitlab.com/fltk/fltk/-/blob/master/test/navigation.cxx) test file.

Maybe your widget did get the focus (check this with Fl::focus()), but it does not show that up (you need to handle the FL_FOCUS and/or FL_UNFOCUS events)?

Comment: I commented out my `CustomButton::handle()` function and just pass the event along to the `Fl_Button::handle()` and I'm still not able to tab away from the `CustomButton`. I can see that the `CustomButton` does have focus when I tab into it, but it won't let go.

I should note that I'm using fltk 1.1.10

Comment: It looks like `Fl_Group::handle()` never enters the `FL_KEYBOARD` case for the Button, but it does for the `Fl_Input`. That case has a call to `navigation(navkey())` which I'm guessing needs to get called in order to move focus off the `CustomButton`